# Why it says expected ',' but i don't see why to use it

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

> I tried to make this
> tutorial:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QGDeafTx5ug, on player
> movement 2d and i get this errors:  Assets\PlayerController.cs(51,37):
> error CS1001: Identifier expected Assets\PlayerController.cs(51,37):
> error CS1003: Syntax error, ',' expected
> Assets\PlayerController.cs(54,44): error CS1001: Identifier expected
> Assets\PlayerController.cs(54,44): error CS1003: Syntax error, ','
> expected

```
 using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using UnityEngine;
    
    public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public float speed;
        public float jumpForce;
        private float moveInput;
    
        private Rigidbody2D rb;
    
        private bool facingRight = true;
    
    
        private bool isGrounded;
        public Transform groundCheck;
        public float checkRadius;
        public LayerMask whatIsGround;
    
        private int extraJumps;
        public int extraJumpsValue;
    
    
        void Start()
        {
            extraJumps = extraJumpsValue;
            rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        }
        void FixedUpdate()
        {
            isGrounded = Physics2D.OverlapCircle(groundCheck.position, checkRadius, whatIsGround);
    
            moveInput = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
            Debug.Log(moveInput);
            rb.velocity = new  Vector2(moveInput * speed, rb.velocity.y);
    
            if(facingRight == false && moveInput > 0){
                Flip();
            } else if(facingRight == true && moveInput < 0){
                Flip();
            }
        }
        
        void Update()
        {
            if(isGrounded == true){
                 extraJumps = extraJumpsValue;
            }
    
            if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode."W") && extraJumps > 0){
                rb.velocity = Vector2.up * jumpForce;
                extraJumps--;
            } else if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode."w") && extraJumps == 0 && isGrounded == true){
                rb.velocity = Vector2.up * jumpForce;
            }
                
        }
    
        void Flip()
        {
            facingRight = !facingRight;
            Vector3 Scaler = transform.localScale;
            Scaler.x *= -1;
            transform.localScale = Scaler;
        }
    
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with `KeyCode."W"` 
This should be `KeyCode.W`

see https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/KeyCode.html